# SQL Change column in view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I start on the views, the view on which I work has multiple joins and by creating one of the columns I got the wrong original table:

```
aer.etat_etude_erdf AS etude_erdf
```

instead of

```
edf.etat_etude_erdf AS etude_erdf
```

I tried with 'alter view' but I did not manage to modify the column. is it possible to modify it completely?

Thank you

Comment: Use `create or replace view` with the correct SQL statement